# Merge columns in crystal report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am working on `crystal` report in visual studio 2008. In crystal report i have two field `BranchName` and `Types`. What i want is if `BranchName` and `Types` are same then merge all columns for that specific row and display only BranchName with **Bold** style in that row.

```
--------------------------------------
Branch Name  |  Types   |   Status   |
--------------------------------------
    abc      |    abc   |            |
--------------------------------------
    xyz      |    mnl   |            |
--------------------------------------
```

and i want it as

```
--------------------------------------
Branch Name  |  Types   |   Status   |
--------------------------------------
               abc                   |
------------------------------------- 
    xyz      |   mnl    |            |
--------------------------------------
```

How can i do this?