# Merge vertically 2 cells with crystal reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, merge

I am using Crystal Reports with Visual Studio 2010. In my report, I have a cross-tab with Users for group rows, Dates for group columns and ID of the Task for summarized fields. I want to merge the Tasks if they have the same values horizontally.

```
          | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 | Date 4 |
User 1    | Task 1 | Task 1 |        | Task 2 |
User 2    |        | Task 3 | Task 3 | Task 4 |
```

And i want it like this:

```
       | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 | Date 4 |
User 1 |      Task 1     |        | Task 2 |
User 2 |        |      Task 3     | Task 4 |
```

How could I do this in my Crystal Report ?
(I already read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600304/merge-columns-in-crystal-report) and it didn't answer my question even with the help of the link in the thread)